# Fcm serviceworker receive message in background but code not executed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
var config = {
    messagingSenderId: "18????????2"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { notificationID: payload.data.notificationID },
        url: "https://myapi/somerestservice",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("remove notification status : " + data.Status + " - Message : " + data.Message);
        }
    });
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
      body:payload.notification.body,
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
```

I receive messages in background without any errors and message appear in browser perfectly

My problem is I need to `execute` some code to delete data from `db`, but any code I added in `setBackgroundMessageHandler` not fired when message received
is there any event fired when message received in background
(in foreground I use `onMessage` and its work nice)

Answer (score 1):

If the `notification` key is set on the message when you send the HTTP/XMPP request (e.g. from your backend), the message handler registered with `setBackgroundMessageHandler` will not be called. Firebase will handle the message for you and display it as-is.

If you need to do something when the message is received while you app is in the background, you can instead use the `data` key on your message; if the `notification` key is omitted, the handler registered with `setBackgroundMessageHandler` will be called and you can handle the payload and customize the notification:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

  // Do you AJAX request here.

  // Customize and show your notification
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title,
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

NB: In addition to displaying the notification yourself, you will also have to manually handle clicking and closing events.

To send the message:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "title": "Hello",
    "body": "How are you?",
    "icon": "https://..."
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

This part of the official docs can be a bit confusing, but some clarifications about when the two message handlers are called can be found here: https://sentinelstand.com/article/handling-firebase-notification-messages-in-your-web-app